# $.getScript works second time around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I was wondering if this is a common issue with jQuery's `$.getScript()`? I have a JS script that uses this feature.

My JS file is really long and I don't think its a good idea for me to post my entire script, so I was just curious if this is a common problem?

I have an `$.ajax` function which is run after pressing a button

```
$.ajax({
   url: thisURL,
   type: "POST",
   crossDomain:true,
   data: searliziedData
}).done(function(data){

var jsPaths = ["http://www.example.com/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js","http://www.example.com/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js","http://www.example.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.js","http://www.example.com/js/image_contents.js"];
$.each(jsPaths, function(i, jsPath) {
    $.getScript(jsPath);
});

   // do something
});
```

So the scripts doesn't get inserted into the site until I press the button **second time around**. I have also tried to insert the `$.getScript` code before the `$.ajax` and again it doesn't execute until second time pressed.

I get no errors or anything from this code.

I've also put in an `alert("test")` inside the `$.each()` function and that gets executed.

You may ask how do I know my script doesn't get executed? I use google chrome's inspect element and under resources I can see what scripts are being executed in the site.

Comment: You could add a `.done()` to the `.getScript()` to see what happens.

Comment: can you explain what would that show me?

Comment: It would tell you that the script has finished loading; in fact, that's pretty important if you want to avoid attempting to load it more than once.

Comment: @Jack do I just add it like this: `$.getScript(jsPath).done();` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime I have an issue with `getScript()` not working on the first page load after clearing cache (or if it only works on the first load) it's because I have something out of order.

I'm going to oversimplify a bit here: the last time I ran into this I was checking to see if the `<body>` element had a particular class, but I was calling the script before the `<body>` tag itself.  On first load `getScript()` wouldn't execute, but on second load it would execute because the document was cached.  In this case the issue isn't specific to `getScript()`, but rather how the cache works.

Another common issue is script dependencies, take this for example:

```
$.getScript('plugin.js');
$.getScript('developers.js');
```

If `developers.js` is dependent on something like plugin functionality in `plugin.js`, there are cases where it's highly likely `developers.js` will fail to run because it was downloaded faster than `plugin.js` and therefor executed first.

A resolution for this would be something like:

```
$.getScript('plugin.js').done(function(){
    $.getScript('developers.js');
});
```

You said your JS file was quite large and inquired if this is a common problem.  I would say yes. When you have a lot going on it's easy to overlook the order of execution of your scripts in relation to each other and the HTML Document.  This is an issue you just have to debug to see if you're missing any dependencies.